# Populating cell in UITableView with unique items

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have an array of URL Links that I'm trying to load into a Grouped UITableView. The goal being that I have numberOfSectionsInTableView return [url count] so I can have number of sections equal to the number of url links. Then in numberOfRowsInSection returns 1 so I only populate 1 URL for each section.

The trouble I'm having is to ensure that cellForRowAtIndexPath won't keep grabbing the first url link. I suspect it's because it's always grabbing the first url because the rowIndex is always zero.

Any ideas how to ensure that each cell in my UITableView is populated with a different url link?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return [newsItems count];
```

}

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return 1;
```

}

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 5;
}

// Configure the cell. Get the title of the news item that was parsed out
int newsItemIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
[cell.textLabel setText:[[newsItems objectAtIndex: newsItemIndex] objectForKey: @"link"]];
return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what i see here you are making many sections with 1 row each...im not sure that ayou are getting the index correctly you can do something like this

```
int newsIntemIndex=indexPath.section
```

that should do it for you